Bar construction of a commutative monoid
Let $M$ be a commutative monoid. Define the bar construction $BM$ as the thin geometric realization of $[p] \mapsto M^p$. I am looking for a reference for the fact that $BM$ is again a commutative monoid.

Graeme Segal. Cohomology of topological groups. In Symposia Mathematica, Vol. IV (INDAM, Rome, 1968/69), pages 377–387. Academic Press, London, 1970.

@ChrisSchommer-Pries : This seems to be very hard to find. Do you have a link?

@UlrichPennig https://dmitripavlov.org/scans/segal-cohomology-of-topological-groups.pdf

@DanRamras Awesome! Thank you!
